# I want to get the row value from the gridview into another gridview and use it for calculation

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to get the value from the gridview  into another gridview and use it for calculation..

my first gridview as

```
  depotcode|depotname|lat_deg|lat_min |lat_sec| lon_deg |lon_min |lon_sec |lat_decimaldegree |lon_decimaldegree|
```

my secondgridview as

```
 depotcode |custwt |custname| lat_deg |lat_min |lat_sec |lon_deg |lon_min |lon_sec |lat_decimaldegree |lon_decimaldegree.|
```

now to calculate difference between the 2longitude i need lon_decimaldegree from gridview1 and use it in second gridview.. please help to do this

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to [this property of the gridview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [this event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to get what you need.